# Don't Show Responsive Paragraph With Bootstrap in mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I Want create paragraph with bootstrap center the page,But in mobile this paragraph isn't in all of width Just half,
my html code:

```
<div class="container">

        <h2 class="slideInLeft">Application</h2>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <p class=" panel-body">Instagram is a mobile,desktop,and r 2010 as a free mobile app
                    exclusively for the iOS operating system. A version for os or videos 
                    digital filters to their images, and add locations 
                    Instagram was its confining of photos to a square</p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

And CSS code:

```
h2 {
color: #669966;
font-family: 'Sofia', 'serif';
font-weight: bold;
  }
.para {
  text-align:center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-family: 'Fira Sans', 'serif';
  font-weight:bold;}
```

And Image of this Wrong Responsive is:

Comment: You could set up a media query like `@media(max-width: 500px){.panel-body{display:none!important;}}` like this the paragraph would not show up when the width of the device is smaller than 500px. Im not quite sure what you need, Your title is asking for something different than the question itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
 <div class ='col-sm-12'>
            <p class="panel-body">Instagram is a mobile,desktop,and r 2010 as a free mobile app
                exclusively for the iOS operating system. A version for os or videos 
                digital filters to their images, and add locations 
                Instagram was its confining of photos to a square.   </p>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

or 
You could refer to this link for further details on using grid what you omitted was to add the class of which grid you wish to use https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp